# Ajax POST não executa a action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net

> Action do Controller

```
public class EstabelecimentoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImportarEstabelecimentos()
    {
        var file = Request.Files["inputFileImportarEstabelecimentos"];


        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
}
```

> Trecho do input HTML

```
Importar <input id="inputFileImportarEstabelecimentos" name="inputFileImportarEstabelecimentos" type="file" onchange="ImportarEstabelecimentos()" />
```

> Trecho javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

});
function ImportarEstabelecimentos() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Estabelecimento/ImportarEstabelecimentos",
        datatype: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        success: function() { alert('Success'); }

        });
}
```

Comment: O ajax está chegando no controller?

Comment: @MayconF.Castro, exatamente esse o problema, o Ajax não está dando erro, mas ele não entra na minha Action do Controller

Comment: na url coloca url: UrlApplication + "/Estabelecimento/ImportarEstabelecimentos"

Comment: @MayconF.Castro, o que seria esse UrlApplication ?

Comment: você consegue abrir a url no navegador? se estiver usando o Chrome, usa a ferramenta de dev (**F12**) e olha a aba *Network*  para ver a chamada e qual resposta está retornado

Comment: É para pegar a url local

Comment: @MayconF.Castro, muito estranho, pois não funciona nenhuma requisição, tentei para outras action e nada, mudei de post para get e também nada..

Comment: Seu ajax está sendo chamado?

Comment: O ajax está correto, talvez ele não esteja sendo chamado. Tenta colocar alguma mensagem na função para poder vê-la no console, ou tente por o evento onchange por código javascript. `$("#campo").on("change", function(){})`

Comment: coloca um `.` aqui: `./Estabelecimento/ImportarEstabelecimentos`

Comment: Retire o `datatype: "JSON", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` se não está esperando um JSON como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você não está postando o arquivo na requisição ajax, faça assim:

```
var form = $("#ID_DO_SEU_FORM");
dataForm = new FormData(form[0]);//IE10+
```

Ao criar a url da sua `Action`, faça assim: `@Url.Action("NOME_DA_ACTION", "NOME_DA_CONTROLLER")`
No seu caso: `@Url.Action("ImportarEstabelecimentos", "Estabelecimento")`

Altere o método da seguinte forma:

```
function ImportarEstabelecimentos() {
    var form = $("#ID_DO_SEU_FORM");
    dataForm = new FormData(form[0]);//IE10+

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ImportarEstabelecimentos", "Estabelecimento")',
        data: dataForm,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Espero ter ajudado!